# Is it possible to use Type.GetType with a dynamically loaded assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have this little bit of code:

```
public static void LoadSomething(Type t)
{            
    var t1 = Type.GetType(t.AssemblyQualifiedName);

    var t2 = t
        .Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .First(ta => ta.AssemblyQualifiedName == t.AssemblyQualifiedName);
}
```

What happens is that t1 is **null** and t2 is **not null**.  I was confused since if I call it like so...

```
LoadSomething(typeof(SomeObject));
```

then **neither** are null but what I am actually doing is more like this (not really, this is massively simplified but it illustrates my point):

```
LoadSomething(Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\....dll").GetTypes().First());
```

So the first part of my question (for my information) is...

In the second case, since the assembly must be loaded up and I found the type out of it, why does `Type.GetType` return null?

And secondly (to actually solve my problem)...

Is there some other way that I could load a type when I only have the assembly qualified name as a string (that I know has been previously loaded by using the Assembly.Load methods)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Is there some other way that I could load a type when I only have the
>   assembly qualified name as a string (that I know has been previously
>   loaded by using the Assembly.Load methods)?

Yes. There is a [`GetType` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_System_Func_System_Reflection_AssemblyName_System_Reflection_Assembly__System_Func_System_Reflection_Assembly_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Type__System_Boolean_) that allows that. It takes an "assembly resolver" function as parameter:

```
public static Type LoadSomething(string assemblyQualifiedName)
{
    // This will return null
    // Just here to test that the simple GetType overload can't return the actual type
    var t0 = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName);

    // Throws exception is type was not found
    return Type.GetType(
        assemblyQualifiedName,
        (name) =>
        {
            // Returns the assembly of the type by enumerating loaded assemblies
            // in the app domain            
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(z => z.FullName == name.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
        },
        null,
        true);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Dynamically loads an assembly
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\...\ClassLibrary1.dll");

    // Load the types using its assembly qualified name
    var loadedType = LoadSomething("ClassLibrary1.Class1, ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank @ken2k, your answer solved one of my problems in my current project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where I dynamically load assemblies into the current appdomain, but `Type.GetType` wouldn't get public types from those assemblies.  I didn't have to go as far as providing an assembly resolver, though.  My assemblies are located in a subdirectory and it started working after I added the subdirectory to the application's probing path in the `app.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Modules;"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**NOTE:** The probing path only works for paths within the application's directory branch.

Answer (score -1):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx

Type.AssemblyQualifiedName Property

Type: System.String
The assembly-qualified name of the Type, which includes the name of the assembly from which the Type was loaded, **or null if the current instance represents a generic type parameter.**

I think it's because the method signature has t as a Type.