# Type.GetType() by string from an already loaded assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, .net-assembly

I've got a small plugin architecture where I load plugins from a custom directory using MEF. For some requirements, I need to create an instance of a `Type` from a class which is contained within one of the plugin assemblies. I'm trying to do this using `Type.GetType()` and the fully qualified name of the type (assembly + namespace + type).

This fails because .NET somehow tries to load the type from the assembly which (obviously) isn't contained in the default probing paths of the executable. This behavior would be fine if the type isn't present yet, however since I already loaded the whole assembly ealier (remember, plugin framework), the assembly in question is already loaded into the current app domain! When I create an instance of the `Type` class in the plugin and return it through some contract, I can use it without any problems.

How can I tell the .NET runtime that it shouldn't load the type from an assembly, but check if the assembly hasn't been already loaded in the current app domain first?

### Classes to reproduce the problem (half-pseudo):

```
// --- MyProject.Contract
public interface IPlugin {
    string GetTypeName();
    Type GetType();
}

// --- MyProject.Plugin
public class SomeType { }

public class MyPlugin : IPlugin {

    public string GetTypeName() {
        return typeof(SomeType).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    }

    public string GetType() {
        return typeof(SomeType);
    }

}

// --- MyProject.App
var assembly   = Assembly.LoadFrom("path/to/pluginfolder/MyPlugin.dll");
var pluginType = assembly.GetExportedTypes().OfType<IPlugin>().FirstOrDefault();
var plugin     = (IPlugin) Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType)

Console.WriteLine(plugin.GetType().Name); // works

// fails because .NET tries to load the assembly AGAIN and doesn't find it
// in the default probing paths
Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType(plugin.GetTypeName()));
```

Oh, and btw: I'm not looking for a solution like e.g. resolving assemblies manually or adding additional probing paths. I want to prevent .NET from being stupid and check the loaded assemblies for the type in question before trying to load an assembly.

Comment: Very hard to believe this code snippet matches your real code.  Crystal ball says that you actually use Assembly.LoadFile().   Which is wrong, use LoadFrom() instead.

Comment: Why not using MEF, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, the snippet doesn't work. I just wrote it from the top of my head in order to further clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @artganify, Making a plugin system, is textbook MEF usage, so i can't understand how a suggestion for applying it using MEF will be irrelevant.

Comment: @OrelEraki Because even MEF would fail here. This is not a problem with the architecture or anything. Try it: Create a `DirectoryCatalog` from a source outside the assembly probing path, return the `AssemblyQualifiedName` from a type within the plugin to the host application and try to create an instance of it.

Comment: Trying it in for the last few minutes, give me few minutes :)

Comment: @artganify, Someone already stumble it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430654/is-it-possible-to-use-type-gettype-with-a-dynamically-loaded-assembly Can be marked as duplicate ?

Comment: @OrelEraki Woohoo. Thank you very much. :) Yes, you can mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @artganify, No problem, was interesting. You can try deleting the question :)