# Type.GetType() returns null

Tags: c#

These all return null, I'd expect the first one to work:

```
 Type.GetType("Namespace.To.My.Type, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
 Type.GetType("Namespace.To.My.Type, MyAssembly")
 Type.GetType("Namespace.To.My.Type")
```

So, in debugging this, I tried this:

```
var aqn = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()[92].GetType("Namespace.To.My.Type").AssemblyQualifiedName; // Namespace.To.My.Type, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Type.GetType(aqn)
```

(where `92` is `MyAssembly`)

which also returns null.

What going on? Is my assembly only half-loaded or something? Surely not, because I can do this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()[92].GetTypes()[161]
```

and find `Namespace.To.My.Type`, and also

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()[92].GetType("Namespace.To.My.Type")
```

**Updates**

- Worth noting that `MyAssembly` has been loaded via `Assembly.Load(path)` immediately before the above code
- I'm in a console app
- the AQN of my type is shown above in a code comment, scroll right
- If I make `GetType` throw, it throws: "Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

**Fuslogvw output:**

> FusionLog: "=== Pre-bind state information ===\r\nLOG: DisplayName = Namespace.To.My.Type, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\n (Fully-specified)\r\nLOG: Appbase = file:///MyConsoleAppPath/bin/Debug/\r\nLOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL\r\nCalling assembly : MyConsoleApp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.\r\n===\r\nLOG: This bind starts in default load context.\r\nLOG: Using application configuration file: D:\MyConsoleAppPath\bin\Debug\MyConsoleApp.exe.Config\r\nLOG: Using host configuration file: \r\nLOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.\r\nLOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).\r\n

Comment: You could use the overload `Type.GetType(string, bool)`, with the bool set to true. That will force an exception in case of an error which might contain more information.

Comment: What fully qualified name you can get with using debugger to watch the return value of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()[92].GetTypes()[161]?

Comment: An obvious scenario is this DLL originally getting loaded in a non-standard way.  AppDomain.LoadFile() and AppDomain.Load(byte[]) are particularly notable as a very evil methods.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to get ahead.

Comment: _"The same bind was seen before, and was failed"_ - restart your application.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah i'm doing that, whats the solution?

Comment: ah Hans you beauty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430654/is-it-possible-to-use-type-gettype-with-a-dynamically-loaded-assembly thanks!

Comment: Per the accepted answer, this can be marked as a duplicate of: [Is it possible to use Type.GetType with a dynamically loaded assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430654/is-it-possible-to-use-type-gettype-with-a-dynamically-loaded-assembly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer: [Is it possible to use Type.GetType with a dynamically loaded assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430654/is-it-possible-to-use-type-gettype-with-a-dynamically-loaded-assembly)

It's because I'd loaded the assembly by `Assembly.Load` - although I still don't understand why this causes the observed problem.

Comment: Could you try using `LoadFrom` instead of `Load`? (`LoadFrom` actually loads dependencies and such too). Also, why cant you use `dynamicAssembly.GetType` instead of `Type.GetType`? Reading your posts it seems you have a reference to the `dynamicAssembly`..